# jQuery generated elements not recognized on $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin using PHP and jQuery, the function below is called when the `<select>` input is changed, so far it works as intended and the inputs are generated properly but when I submit the form, the generated elements are undefined when called in `$_POST`.

```
<?php

function random_event() {
    global $wpdb;

    //Table for all the event details
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."random_event";

    // Table to store all banner stores
    $tablename2 = $wpdb->prefix."random_event_banner_stores";

    //Table for store all poster
    $tablename4 = $wpdb->prefix."random_event_poster";

    // Table storing all user registrations
    $tablename3 = $wpdb->prefix."random_event_winners";

    //Junction table to map the poster to banner store
    $tablename5 = $wpdb->prefix."random_event_poster_banner";

    //Junction table to map the poster to event
    $tablename6 = $wpdb->prefix."random_event_poster_event";


    $tablename5 = $wpdb->prefix."random_event_poster_banner";

    $sql = "select event.*, banner.name as banner_name, banner.id as banner_id from $tablename as event left join $tablename2 as banner on banner.id = event.store_id";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    $update_this_event = -1;
    $banner_stores = [];
    //Deletion
    if(isset($_POST['delete_event'])) {


        $event_id = esc_sql($_POST['event_id']);

        $sql = "DELETE from $tablename WHERE id= '" . $event_id . "'";

        try{
            $event = $wpdb->query($sql);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "<script>console.log($e);</script>";
        }

    } else if(isset($_POST['update_event'])){

        $update_this_event = intval(esc_sql($_POST['event_id']));
        $banner_store_id = esc_sql($_POST['banner_id']);
        $name = esc_sql($_POST['banner_store_name']);
        $description = esc_sql($_POST['banner_store_description']);
        $location_note = esc_sql($_POST['banner_store_location_note']);
        $address = esc_sql($_POST['banner_store_address']);
        $status = esc_sql($_POST['banner_store_status']);

        $sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET name = '" . $name . "'
        , description = '" . $description . "'
        , location_note = '" . $location_note . "'
        , address = '" . $address . "'
        , status =  '" . $status . "' WHERE id = '" . $banner_store_id . "'";

        try{
            $participants = $wpdb->query($sql);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "<script>console.log($e);</script>";
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['select_update_event'])){

        $update_this_event = intval(esc_sql($_POST['event_id']));

        // $pssql = "select * from $tablename2";
        // $banner_stores = $wpdb->get_results($pssql);

        $pssql = "select $tablename2.* from $tablename2 left join $tablename on $tablename2.id = $tablename.store_id where $tablename.store_id is null";
        // $pssql = "select * from $tablename2";
        $banner_stores = $wpdb->get_results($pssql);

        $pssql2 = "select $tablename2.* from $tablename2 left join $tablename on $tablename2.id = $tablename.store_id where $tablename.id = '".$update_this_event."'";
        $current_banner_store = $wpdb->get_results($pssql2);

        if(count($current_banner_store) != 0) {
            array_push($banner_stores, $current_banner_store[0]);
        }

        $poster_sql = "select ap.*, a.name as poster_name, ap.qty as qty from $tablename6 as ap inner join  $tablename4 as a on a.id = ap.poster_id where ap.event_id = $update_this_event";

        $poster_event = $wpdb->get_results($poster_sql);

        $poster_petone = [];
        foreach($results as $result) {
            if($result->id == $update_this_event) {
                $poster_sql = "select a.* from $tablename5 as ap inner join $tablename4 as a on a.id = ap.poster_id where banner_store_id = ".$result->store_id;

                $poster_petone = $wpdb->get_results($poster_sql);
            }
        }


    }else if(isset($_POST['cancel_update_event'])){

        $update_this_event = -1;

    }else if (isset($_POST['save_update_event'])) {

        $update_this_event = intval(esc_sql($_POST['event_id']));
        $title = esc_sql($_POST['title']);
        $qty = 0;
        $description = esc_sql($_POST['description']);
        $prize = esc_sql($_POST['prize']);
        $event_code = esc_sql($_POST['event_code']);
        $event_from = esc_sql($_POST['event_from']);
        $event_to = esc_sql($_POST['event_to']);
        $banner_store_id = esc_sql($_POST['banner_store_id']);

        if(isset($_POST['poster_ids'])){
            $poster_ids = $_POST['poster_ids'];
            $poster_qtys = $_POST['poster_qty'];
        }

        $query = "UPDATE $tablename set title='$title',description='$description',event_code='$event_code',valid_from='$event_from',valid_to='$event_to',store_id='$banner_store_id', prize = '$prize' ";
        $query .= "where id = $update_this_event";

        $result_insert = $wpdb->query($query);

        $delete_query = "delete from $tablename6 where event_id =  $update_this_event";
        $wpdb->query($delete_query);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($poster_ids); $i++) {
            $poster_id = esc_sql($poster_ids[$i]);
            $poster_qty = esc_sql($poster_qtys[$i]);

            $poster_query = "INSERT INTO $tablename6 (event_id,poster_id, qty) values ";
            $poster_query .= "('$update_this_event','$poster_id','$poster_qty');";

            $poster_insert = $wpdb->get_results($poster_query);
            $poster_result = $wpdb->insert_id;
        }

        $update_this_event = -1;

        $sql = "select event.*, banner.name as banner_name, banner.id as banner_id from $tablename as event left join $tablename2 as banner on banner.id = event.store_id";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    }

    ?>

    <style type="text/css" emb-not-inline="">

    .table-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    .banner-button {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 13px;
        min-width: 75px;
    }

    table {
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    table th {
        background-color: #23282d;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    table th:first-child{
        border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    table th:last-child{
        border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    }

    table {
        border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    }

    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <h1>View All events</h1>

    <br/>

    <div class="table-container" style="
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    ">

    <table cellpadding="10" border=1 style="border-style: solid #AAA">
        <tr>

            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Prize</th>
            <th>event Code</th>
            <th>banner Store</th>
            <th>poster Qty</th>
            <th>Validity</th>
            <th>QR code</th>
            <th>Action</th>

        </tr>

        <?php
        foreach($results as $result) {

            if($update_this_event == $result->id) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <form method="post" name="formtest1" id="formtest1">

                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $result->title ?>"/> </td>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $result->description ?>"/> </td>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="prize" value="<?php echo $result->prize ?>"/> </td>

                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="event_code" value="<?php echo $result->event_code ?>"/> </td>
                        <td valign="top">

                            <!-- <select onChange="changebanner(this)" id="banner_store_id" name="banner_store_id"> -->
                            <select id="banner_store_id" name="banner_store_id">
                                <?php
                                foreach($banner_stores as $pstore) {

                                    if($result->banner_id == $pstore->id) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option SELECTED value="<?php echo $pstore->id?>"> <?php echo $pstore->name ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }else {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $pstore->id?>"> <?php echo $pstore->name ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <div id="poster_div">

                                <table border="0" cellpadding=5>
                                    <?php
                                    if(count($poster_event) == 0) {

                                        for($i = 0; $i < count($poster_petone); $i++)
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="poster_ids[]" value="<?php echo $poster_petone[$i]->id?>"><?php echo $poster_petone[$i]->name?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" name="poster_qty[]" placeholder= "Qty Allocation" value="<?php echo $poster_petone[$i]->qty ?>">
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }else {
                                        for($i = 0; $i < count($poster_event); $i++)
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="hidden" name="poster_ids[]" value="<?php echo $poster_event[$i]->poster_id?>"><?php echo $poster_event[$i]->poster_name?></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="poster_qty[]" placeholder= "Qty Allocation" value="<?php echo $poster_event[$i]->qty?>"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top"><input id="event_from" name="event_from" type="text" value="<?php echo $result->valid_from ?>"/> - <input name="event_to" id="event_to" type="text" value="<?php echo $result->valid_to ?>"/> </td>
                        <td valign="top"></td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $result->id ?> ">
                            <input type="submit" name="save_update_event" value="save" class="banner-button">
                            <input type="submit" name="cancel_update_event" value="cancel" class="banner-button">
                        </td>

                        </form>
                    </tr>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><?php echo $result->title ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php echo $result->description ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php echo $result->prize ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php echo $result->event_code ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php echo $result->banner_name ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php get_poster_of_event($result->id ) ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php echo $result->valid_from ?> - <?php echo $result->valid_to ?></td>
                    <td valign="top"><?php generate_random("https://generic.com/event/?random=".$result->event_code, $result->title) ?> </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <form method="post" name="formtest" id="formtest">
                            <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $result->id ?> "/>
                            <input type="submit" name="delete_event" value="delete" class="banner-button"/>
                        </form>
                        <form method="post" name="formtest" id="formtest">
                            <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $result->id ?> "/>
                            <input type="submit" name="select_update_event" value="update" class="banner-button"/>
                        </form>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>

<script>

let jQueryNC = jQuery.noConflict();

jQueryNC( function() {
    jQueryNC( "#event_to" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    jQueryNC( "#event_from" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

} );

jQueryNC("body").on("change", "#banner_store_id", function() {
  changebanner(jQueryNC(this));
});

function changebanner(e){
    let jQueryNC = jQuery.noConflict();
            jQueryNC( "#poster_div" ).html("Loading...");
            let formData = new FormData(); // creates an object, optionally fill from <form>
            let value = jQueryNC("#banner_store_id").val();
            console.log(e.value);

            formData.append('poster_id', value);
                formData.append('action', 'get_poster');

                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/admin/admin-post.php");
                xhr.send(formData);

                xhr.onload = () => {
                    let posters = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                    let htmldiv = '<table border=0 cellpadding=5>';

                    for(let i = 0; i < posters.length; i++)
                    {
                        htmldiv += '<tr>';
                        htmldiv += '<td><input type="hidden" name="poster_ids[]" value="'+posters[i].id+'">'+posters[i].name+'</td>';
                        htmldiv += '<td><input type="text" name="poster_qty[]" placeholder= "Qty Allocation" value="'+posters[i].qty+'"></td>';
                        htmldiv += '</tr>';

                    }
                    htmldiv += '</table>';

                    jQueryNC("#poster_div").html(htmldiv);
                }

        }
</script>

<?php
} ?>
```

Clarification: when the select input is not changed, the inputs inside container div are recognized upon submitting without any errors, but when the contents of container div are changed via changebanner; the new inputs and tables are created but if it is submitted, the inputs like poster_ids[] is not recognized by $_POST['poster_ids']

**EDIT** added the entire code in hopes of clarifying the problem

Comment: `shows an undefined error` - what error? Edit your question, add the *exact* error.  Also, I am not sure I understand but it looks like your inputs are added **after** the form has already been POSTed, right?  That would mean they're not there on the first POST, which is exactly what you're seeing .. ?

Comment: editted the error to be more specific, also the inputs are added when the select input is changed, not after the form is posted

Comment: how are you calling the function? Are you using something like $("body").on("change", "#myID", function(){changeSELECTED($(this).....)});

Comment: @Icewine added the element that calls the function

Comment: Read through your code again.  Initially, your form has a `data_store_id` value.  When that is changed, you create `formData`, and append `data_id` and `action` to it.  Then you POST that `formData`.  The only thing you POST are those 2 values.    There is no `data_ids`, there is no `data_qty`, and trying to access them in `$_POST` will not work because they are not there.  **After** your POST is finished, you add some new stuff to the form ([`xhr.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload) fires when the request is finished).

Comment: You can check this by looking in your browser's devtools, and looking at the network tab - you will see the xhr request, and exactly what is sent.

Comment: added a few more details and clarifications, i apologize for being unclear as i initially thought the provided data was enough

Comment: What you have added doesn't change anything ... your `FormData` is created empty.  It does not include any fields from your form.  If you want to populate it from the fields of your form, [you need to pass the form element to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Comment: added the entire code to clarify the problem, changed data to poster and banner to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to explain the issue in my comments but maybe it will be easier to see here.

- Your initial form on page load has a bunch of inputs etc in it, including some `poster_ids` and `poster_qty`.
- If you submit that form, by clicking the submit button, a standard HTML form submission via POST happens.  All the inputs that exist in the form on page load will be sent in the request, and your PHP will get all of them.
- But if you don't submit the form, and instead change the selected `#banner_store_id` option, some Javascript takes over.  That JS will do a few things:

  - Create an empty `formData` object, *ignoring everything currently in your form*;
  - Add 2 new key/value pairs to that `formData`
  - POST those 2 values to your PHP.  Note this is not a standard HTML POST like the one that happens when you click submit, it is an AJAX POST.  It is essentially independent of the `<form>` on the page, and it will only POST the fields from the form if you specifically add them.  The code you have does not do that, and so *does not include any of your existing form fields*.
  - If you try to use `$_POST['poster_ids']` in the PHP which receives this JS POST, it will fail, because those fields were not in the request.  The only things there are a `poster_id` and an `action`.

If you **do** want to include all the fields in your form in the data you POST via JS when changing `#banner_store_id`, you need to create a `formData` with the form itself, [as shown in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('formtest1');
let formData = new FormData(myForm);
```

If you do this, then all the inputs on your form are bundled up and included in that `formData`, and just like with the normal POST will all be sent to your PHP.

Here's the relevant part of your code, commented to explain it further:

```js
function changebanner(e) {
    // Create a new FormData object - **NOTE** it is empty!  You have not passed
    // in your existing form, so none of the form inputs already on the page are
    // in FormData.  If you POSTed it right away $_POST would be completely empty.
    let formData = new FormData();

    // Now add 2 items to it
    formData.append('poster_id', value);
    formData.append('action', 'get_poster');

    // Now make your POST, and send formData, which has just those 2 items
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/admin/admin-post.php");
    xhr.send(formData);

    // The POST is done, you sent poster_id and action and nothing else to your PHP
}
```

Comment: @Raphael Does this help?

Comment: it didn't solve the problem itself but your answer gave enough knowledge to arrive at the solution, i ended up adding form="formtest1" to the generated inputs, thank you very much for the wonderful explanations

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the onchange(this) in the select and instead use the jQuery on.("change").

Without seeing the exact error or what you have tried it is hard to say exactly but trying to access a variable that has not be created yet often gives an undefined because you are trying to access it before it exists. By using the jQuery on function you can find things added after DOM has loaded.

Good luck.

```js
$("body").on("change", "#data_store_id", function() {
  changeSELECTED($(this));
});

function changeSELECTED(e) {

  let jQueryNC = jQuery.noConflict();
  jQueryNC("#container_div").html("Loading...");
  let formData = new FormData(); // creates an object, optionally fill from <form>

  formData.append('data_id', e.value);
  formData.append('action', 'get_data');

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/adminfolder/admin-post.php");
  xhr.send(formData);

  xhr.onload = () => {

    let datas = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    let htmldiv = '<table border=0 cellpadding=5>';
    for (let i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
      htmldiv += '<tr>';
      htmldiv += '<td><input type="hidden" name="data_ids[]" value="' + datas[i].id + '">' + datas[i].name + '</td>';
      htmldiv += '<td><input type="text" name="data_qty[]" placeholder= "Qty Allocation" value="' + datas[i].qty + '"></td>';
      htmldiv += '</tr>';

    }
    htmldiv += '</table>';

    jQueryNC("#container_div").html(htmldiv);
  }

}
```

```html
<select id="data_store_id" name="data_store_id">
  <?php
        foreach($data_stores as $dstore) {
        if($result->data_id == $dstore->id) {
            ?>
    <option SELECTED value="<?php echo $dstore->id?>">
      <?php echo $dstore->name ?>
    </option>
    <?php
        }else {
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $dstore->id?>">
        <?php echo $dstore->name ?>
      </option>
      <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: tried this and still getting undefined variable: data_ids